# Javascript Unit Testing in Symfony

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, symfony, tdd

So some context:

We use Symfony to load our assets (as we have quite a few dependencies (Underscore, Marionette, Backbone, .. etc) and we run Javascript unit tests, using Jasmine. So to run them within our CI server, we use PhantomJS to hit the spec Symfony route. The problem then comes with the speed of it being run in dev mode.

What options do we have running Jasmine tests properly (considering our dependencies are managed through a Symfony Twig template) through a CLI tool rather than hitting them via a URL?

Comment: A way we thought of going, is changing the way assets are loaded, see: http://konradpodgorski.com/blog/2014/06/23/better-way-to-work-with-assets-in-symfony-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up having to convert from using Assetic to [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)